# Why does the write(int b) method of OutputStream exist?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Java OutputStream.write() Takes Integer but Writes Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407893/why-java-outputstream-write-takes-integer-but-writes-bytes)

Why does the `write()` method of the `OutputStream` class take an integer instead of a byte when it actually writes data byte by byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is consistent w/ `IntputStream.read()` and since most operations (sum, mul, div, etc) are promoted to int, it removes the need to constantly cast to `byte`.

I think it's ok.

Comment: How does it deal with the other 3 bytes? Does it preserve the whole `int` or only keep the low-order byte? (I'm just putting out there to try to keep this as complete as possible)

Comment: @jili, the lowest byte out of the 4 in the int is written only by spec... of course no one can stop you from doing whatever you please.

Comment: But there's a pretty good why InputStream has to use ints (well something larger byte) which doesn't hold for the OutputStream: InputStream needs some guardian value to say that it has encountered EOF which means we have to represent 2^8+1 values. But sure all the automatic widening means you barely ever have bytes anyhow.

Comment: @Voo, if you read an int, check it for less than 0, then you can just do out.write(int) w/o the cast. to put it simply you can't just get a `byte`, unless do byte[index].

Comment: @Voo, on a side note, virtually I have precluded use of streams, chaining them is sort of cool, however one of the reason for inefficient IO is the multiple buffers+extra layers.

Answer (score 1):

It actually writes a single byte from that int (the 8 low-order bits). See the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29

**Edit**: I did some digging and found this: [Why Java OutputStream.write() Takes Integer but Writes Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407893/why-java-outputstream-write-takes-integer-but-writes-bytes)

Comment: I think the question is "why didn't the designers of the class use the signature `write(byte b)` instead of `write(int b)`"?

Comment: thanks i am actully asking this

Comment: @sheo: have a look at the link in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to write either signed or unsigned byte.  Most byte streams assume unsigned bytes and the matching InputStream.read() reads a non-negative `int` which you can cast to `(byte)` to make it signed.

---

If you create an readObject and writeObject you will be given a ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutptuStream to read/write your custom serialization format for your object.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos)
    throws IOException {
  oos.defaultWriteObject();
  // Write/save additional fields
  oos.write(byteField);
  oos.writeObject(new java.util.Date());
}

// assumes "static java.util.Date aDate;" declared
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
  ois.defaultReadObject();
  // Read/initialize additional fields
  byteField = oos.read();
  aDate = (java.util.Date)ois.readObject();
}
```