# What does FileOutputStream.write(int b) do?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Java OutputStream.write() Takes Integer but Writes Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407893/why-java-outputstream-write-takes-integer-but-writes-bytes)

The documentation for `FileOutputStream.write(int b)` states that it writes the byte to the file, but the argument is an integer. Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It writes the least significant byte of the `int` argument to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It actually only writes the lowest order byte from that int. This was actually debated before: [Why does the write(int b) method of OutputStream exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459944/why-does-the-writeint-b-method-of-outputstream-exist)